# Complex LINQ Query Reference Error

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am getting this error while querying a LINQ using two tables from two different edmx files. The query runs as,
Simply i want name of the Department and Designation who matches with id and user having that Department and Designation in its **usermaster** table as well **Routemaster** also
Where as 
uid = Local Variable having session value

```
  var qryRoute = (from rm in db.RouteMasters
                        from um in db.UserMasters
                        from dm in db.DeptMasters
                        from desgm in db2.DESG_MASTER
                        where um.UserID == uid 
                        && rm.UnitID == um.UnitID 
                        && rm.ForDept == um.DeptID 
                        && rm.ReqDept == dm.DeptID 
                        && rm.ReqDesg == desgm.ID 
                        && rm.RouteType == "General" 
                        && rm.IsActive == 1
                        select new
                        {
                            rm.RouteID,
                            rm.UnitID,
                            rm.ForDept,
                            rm.RouteType,
                            rm.ReqDept,
                            rm.ReqDesg,
                            dm.Department,
                            desgm.DESG_ID,
                            rm.Seq,
                            rm.IsActive

                        });

        RouteMaster RM;
        foreach (var i in qryRoute)
        {
            RM = new RouteMaster();
            RM.RouteID = i.RouteID;
            RM.UnitID = i.UnitID;
            RM.ForDept = i.ForDept;
            RM.RouteType = i.RouteType;
            RM.ReqDept = i.ReqDept;
            RM.ReqDesg = i.ReqDesg;
            RM.ReqDeptName = i.Department;
            RM.ReqDesgName = i.DESG_ID;
            RM.Seq = i.Seq;
            RM.IsActive = i.IsActive;
            obj.RouteList.Add(RM);
        }
```

db and db2 are instances to two different edmx files.

Showing Error: **The specified LINQ expression contains references to queries that are associated with different contexts.**

Any ideas to solve this issue?

Comment: Error is quit clear to me: You cannot create queries like this using two contexts. Either get the data separately and create the join in-memory or create a context in which all related models live.

Comment: I have used in another query when I am joining two tables, I didn't receive and error there, but while joining 4 tables it shows error, did u find any mistake in joining tables? @PeterBons

Comment: You might have materialized the queries first in the other scenario. Can you post that other query as well?

Comment: @PeterBons as I have answered below thanks for your time , its worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found answer 
By Enabling

```
MultipleActiveResultSets=True
```

In connectionstring, I have changed my query into below,

```
        var qryRoute = (from rm in db.RouteMasters
                        from um in db.UserMasters
                        where um.UserID == uid
                        && rm.UnitID == um.UnitID
                        && rm.ForDept == um.DeptID
                        && rm.RouteType == "General"
                        && rm.IsActive == 1
                        select new
                        {
                            rm.RouteID,
                            rm.UnitID,
                            rm.ForDept,
                            rm.RouteType,
                            rm.ReqDept,
                            rm.ReqDesg,
                            rm.Seq,
                            rm.IsActive
                        });
        obj.RouteList = new List<RouteMaster>();
        foreach (var i in qryRoute)
        {
            obj.RouteList.Add(new RouteMaster
           {
               RouteID = i.RouteID,
               UnitID = i.UnitID,
               ForDept = i.ForDept,
               RouteType = i.RouteType,
               ReqDept = i.ReqDept,
               ReqDesg = i.ReqDesg,
               ReqDeptName = db.DeptMasters.FirstOrDefault(x => x.DeptID == i.ReqDept).Department,
               ReqDesgName = db2.DESG_MASTER.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == i.ReqDesg).DESG_ID,
               Seq = i.Seq,
               IsActive = i.IsActive
           });
        }
```